# socketio: data loss due to socket getting closed due to transport error

Tags: javascript, python, socket.io, flask-socketio

I've been trying very hard to figure this out but no luck so far. 
So I am sending some data from server to client using socket in a loop however the client is unable to receive all the data and closes the socket in the middle of data transmission for no reason.

As you can see in the image below client successfully receives data till 11th iteration of the loop(refer to the server code below) however after that socket is closed cause of transport error. What possibly could I be doing wrong here?

Client side logs

[image]

Server side logs

[image]

(Python) server side code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash, redirect, jsonify, make_response
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, disconnect

import time

from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app, engineio_logger=True)

@socketio.on('run_tgt')
def run_tg(tg_args):
    for x in range(20):
         time.sleep(2)
         emit('tg_output',x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

(Javascript) client side code

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js"></script>
 var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port );
 function run_tg() {
     socket.emit('run_tgt', { 'data': 'data'});
     socket.on('tg_output', function(tg_output) {
         console.log(tg_output);
         $("#output_div").append(tg_output);
     });
 }
```

Comment: Are you using eventlet or gevent? If yes, did you monkey patch the standard library so that it becomes green thread friendly?

Comment: Hi Miguel appreciate your reply, I am using gevent and yes I did monkey patch

Comment: @Miguel I updated the code snippet to add more details

Comment: @Miguel just looked a bit more into gevent monkey patch and everything seems to working find after moving the monkey patch line to absolute top. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by adding monkey patch to the top of the script

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
```

Also set async_handlers to true

```
socketio = SocketIO(app, async_handlers=True, engineio_logger=True)
```